# Oracle call to Java method on another machine

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, interop, java-stored-procedures

I am not allowed to compile the java class into the instance of Oracle we're running on, per architects request, so I am looking for alternatives.  The requirement is to utilize a java library located on an application server on the network.  Is it possible to call a java method located on another machine from PL/SQL?  I found [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_externproc.htm#i1019726) talking about external procedures in Oracle, but I'm not sure that it allows for this.  As a side not, the performance would also have to be fast enough to be used in batch processing of thousands or millions of calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the best you can do is add entries to another table which your Java process polls to get each or batches of messages.  Oracle is not really designed for message processing.

In any case, I would discuss this with your Architect what to do as he is the expert. ;)

If your Oracle system can't do the job, you may need to have a solution which doesn't use Oracle.

Comment: Thanks. We are currently discussing the issue and there is alternative similar to yours but with step by step scheduling instead of polling. I'm curious, why did you rule out the External Procedure approach?

Comment: @Alex Mostly because the last time I used it (ten+ years ago) it was really slow. Its likely to be better now.

Comment: It does look better now, but you still have the problem that your communications need to be fast enough that its not better to use your library as the external procedure.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some way to cache the external procedure to run locally after the first call, or just load it from a remote location to run locally, but I guess that's impossible.  Thanks for your insight.

Comment: You can cache some of the work it does, however it will always have some overhead and unless you call the method asynchronous it will take longer than calling the library as the external procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1.) We solved a similar problem by making PL/SQL call HTTP using UTL_HTTP and then let the app-server call the java procedure. We did this to interface our Oracle Database with Oracle Reports. The PL/SQL fired an HTTP Request which was received by the app-server which called Java. The Java can call back PL/SQL via normal JDBC.

2.) You might not be able to load that java proc, but maybe you can create some other java stored procedure that can invoke it using RMI.

3.) AQ is another method. Basically you can Queue a message using AQ and use JMS on the App Server to Dequeue it and use it.

Option 3 would be the fastest, though we have tried option 1 and the latency for this is not as much as you might it. It also offers a way to do some parallel processing by running multiple requests in parallel.